# sum of values in next column for top 3 values of previous column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns in excel (A, B and C). A contains sector name, B contains cash for sector and C contains asset for sector. 
I am trying to get sum of values in a column in C in excel based on criteria in column A and B. My criteria are:
1. Criteria is filter sector name for ex. sum for "ABC" 
2. Column B has cash value for sectors. Get top 3 cash values for sector. for ex. top 3 cash for ABC sector.

Now, I need to get sum of values in column C for based on 1 and 2 criteria.
[Image has Column A, B and C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cehW4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use Pivot Table to show the Top 3 Values.

Or

**Using Formula**

=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE((A2:A5="Abc")*(B2:B5<>"")*C2:C5,{1,2,3}))

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use excel formula.

Comment: Formula solution added in the original answer.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. In the formula shared by you, it is taking sum of top 3 values in Column C but I want to sort the data based on column B and take sum of values in Column C i.e. take top 3 values of column B and then do sum of values in column C.